# Expending tk.Frame and it's children for an Attribute Editor like GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Python 3.12
Windows 10

[image]

I'm trying to create a property editor using tkinter. Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import colorchooser
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile 
from tkinter import ttk  

# Third party
from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    from ctypes import windll
    windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

LABEL_WIDTH = 14   
PADX = 5
PADY = 3

class StringWidget(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, default=""):
        ''''''
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=label, anchor="e", width=LABEL_WIDTH)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.insert(0, default)
        
        self.label.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.entry.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)

class FileWidget(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, default=""):
        ''''''
        print(parent.winfo_width())
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=parent.winfo_width())
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=label, anchor="e", width=LABEL_WIDTH)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.insert(0, default)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Browse")

        self.label.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.entry.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.btn.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)

class Point3DWidget(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, minv:int=0, maxv:int=10, default:int=0, incr:int=1, format="%.0f"):
        ''''''
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.strv = tk.StringVar()
        self.strv.set(default)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=label, anchor='e', width=LABEL_WIDTH)
        self.spinbox1 = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=minv, to=maxv, increment=incr, format=format, textvariable=self.strv, wrap=True)
        self.spinbox2 = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=minv, to=maxv, increment=incr, format=format, textvariable=self.strv, wrap=True)
        self.spinbox3 = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=minv, to=maxv, increment=incr, format=format, textvariable=self.strv, wrap=True)
        
        self.label.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.spinbox1.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.spinbox2.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
        self.spinbox3.pack(side="left", padx=PADX)
          

class AttributeEditor(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Theme", font=('bold'))
        
        self.sw = StringWidget(self, "String Widget", "Inigo")
        self.fw = FileWidget(self, "File Widget", "Inigo")
        self.pw = Point3DWidget(self, "Point 3D Widget", 0, 10, 6)
        
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=PADX, pady=PADY)
        
        self.sw.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=PADY)
        self.fw.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=PADY)
        self.pw.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=PADY)
        
        separator = ttk.Separator(self, orient='horizontal')
        separator.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=PADX, padx=PADY)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Attribute Editor")
    root.geometry("380x360")

    # Create a ScrolledFrame widget
    sf = ScrolledFrame(root)
    sf.pack(side="top", expand=1, fill="both")

    # Bind the arrow keys and scroll wheel
    sf.bind_arrow_keys(root)
    sf.bind_scroll_wheel(root)

    # Create a frame within the ScrolledFrame
    inner_frame = sf.display_widget(AttributeEditor)

    root.mainloop()
```

When ever I resize the main window, the desired expending behavior I'm looking for is:

1. In StringWidget *entry* should stretch till end of the window.
2. In Filewidget the entry should take the remaining space between label and button and stretched to cover the space.
3. The 3 spinners should be stretched till the end of the window and should take equal space between label and window end.

For reference

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to:

- set `fit_width=True` when calling `sf.display_widget(...)` to expand the *inner frame* to the width of the canvas of `ScrolledFrame`
- call `self.columnconfigure(0, weight)` inside `AttributeEditor.__init__()` so that all child frames created inside it in column 0 will use all the horizontal available space
- add `fill="x"` and `expand=1` in `self.entry.pack(...)` inside `StringWidget.__init__()` to fulfill item #1
- add `fill="x"` and `expand=1` in `self.entry.pack(...)` inside `FileWidget.__init__()` to fulfill item #2
- add `fill="x"` and `expand=1` in those `self.spinboxX.pack(...)` inside `Point3DWidget.__init__()` to fulfill item #3

Note also that in order to see the above result, you need to resize the window to a wider width.

Below is the required changes:

```py
...

class StringWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, default=""):
        ...
        self.entry.pack(side="left", padx=PADX, fill="x", expand=1)

class FileWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, default=""):
        ...
        self.entry.pack(side="left", padx=PADX, fill="x", expand=1)
        ...

class Point3DWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label:str, minv:int=0, maxv:int=10, default:int=0, incr:int=1, format="%.0f"):
        ...
        self.spinbox1.pack(side="left", padx=PADX, fill="x", expand=1)
        self.spinbox2.pack(side="left", padx=PADX, fill="x", expand=1)
        self.spinbox3.pack(side="left", padx=PADX, fill="x", expand=1)

class AttributeEditor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    root.geometry("800x360") # create wider window
    ...
    inner_frame = sf.display_widget(AttributeEditor, fit_width=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

The result:

[image]